# Google maps in android should be zoomable but not scrollable

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps-utils

I have implemented a MapView in android. 
I need to achieve following things in maps

1. Maps should not be scrollable (Achieved using setClickable() to false)
2. Maps should not be scrollable (as setClickable is false, Map is not zoomable)

Answer (score 1):

Enable the zoom gestures on your map object and disable the scroll gestures:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable scroll in `MapFragment` using:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```